# How to train a model to recognize the pronunciation of a syllabe

Tags: python, random-forest, natural-language

I would like to train a model able to predict the syllabe pronunciation of french words.

So, I created a set of syllabized word and for each syllabe I've its pronunciation code. Example: The word `parkinson` is syllabised like this : `par-kin-son` and its pronunciation code is `paR-kin-sOn`. I choosed a english word for clarity but in reality I've a training set of french word.

First, I've created a table of symbols for syllabes:

```
symbols_input = [' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
                 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
                 'x', 'y', 'z', 'à', 'â', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'î', 'ï', 'ô',
                 'û', 'ü']
```

And for pronunciation codes:

```
symbols_output = [' ', '1', '2', '5', '8', '9', '@', 'E', 'G', 'N', 'O', 'R',
                  'S', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                  'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
                  '§', '°']
```

What I do after that is convert my syllabes and pronunciation code into vectors by using the following function:

```
def convert_syllabe_2_vector(syllabe, table):
    """Helper function to convert a syllabe into a vector of integer values."""
    return [table[letter] for letter in syllabe]
```

Exemple:

```
>>> convert_syllabe_2_vector('par', symbol_input)
16 1 18
>>> convert_syllabe_2_vector('par', symbol_output)
27 14 11
```

Since the longest syllabe in my set is 8 char, and the longest pronunciation code is 6, the next thing I do is padding my vector to zero like this:
`16 01 18 00 00 00 00 00` and `27 14 11 00 00 00`

Because in french, previous syllabe and next syllabe can have influences on the pronunciation I form a bigger of 8 * 3 dimensions. So, for `par` syllabe, it will give me:

```
# empty                 par                    -kin
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16 01 18 00 00 00 00 00 11 09 14 00 00 00 00 00
```

and the correct prediction `paR`:

```
27 14 11 00 00 00
```

Do you know a better approach ? Is it right to say it's a classification problem and not a regression one ? What kind of model could fit properly ? I tried a *Random Forest Classifier* it seems to work but I suspect there is many overfitting and training uses a lot of RAM. I also tried to normalize my vector by dividing them by 38, the number of symbols of each table and then multiplying the predicted output by 38 again but the results I obtained were terribles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to model this is using Recurrent Neural Networks (Seq2Seq models).

There are fair amount of tutorials available online.

- https://github.com/cmusphinx/g2p-seq2seq
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/create-a-word-pronunciation-sequence-to-sequence-model-using-amazon-sagemaker/

Edit - 
General classification models treat rows/records independently. So when you train a simple classifier, it is going to predict pronunciation of the whole at based on only current feature set rather than based on previous state (which is what you want).

If you want a normal classifier to predict sequence then you need either add the previous state in feature set (difficult when the size changes dynamically) or change the model architecture to add memory (which is a better solution).

The architecture/design of RNNs is created to consider sequential input(or  memory). RNN and its variants are widely used for sequential predictions like predicting next word or sentence generation.

how do they work - https://towardsdatascience.com/learn-how-recurrent-neural-networks-work-84e975feaaf7

Comment: could you elaborate a bit ?